# C# treat db null values as empty in JSON file

Tags: c#, json

I have some dump problem with converting decimal NULL values from database to JSON file. I have sql procedure which returns values from database. This procedure is called by C# function, which convert all values into JSON file. Currently, when procedure returns following values: [stored procedure results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6vvt.png) then C# function will return JSON formatted in below manner:

```
[{"Attribute1":1,"Attribute2":"Test","Attribute3":"Test","Attribute4":2.00,"Attribute5":12.32}
{"Attribute1":2,"Attribute2":"Test2","Attribute3":"Test2","Attribute4":-1,"Attribute5":-1}]
```

I am processing returned values using below C# code:

```
i.Attribute1 = reader.IsDBNull(Attribute1) ? -1 : reader.GetInt32(Attribute1);
i.Attribute2 = reader.IsDBNull(Attribute2) ? null : reader.GetString(Attribute2);
i.Attribute3 = reader.IsDBNull(Attribute3) ? null : reader.GetString(Attribute3);
i.Attribute4 = reader.IsDBNull(Attribute4) ? -1 : reader.GetDecimal(Attribute4);
i.Attribute5 = reader.IsDBNull(Attribute5) ? -1 : reader.GetDecimal(Attribute5);
```

and now my question is there any way to return empty values for null decimal from database in order to get below JSON?

```
[{"Attribute1":1,"Attribute2":"Test","Attribute3":"Test","Attribute4":2.00,"Attribute5":12.32} 
{"Attribute1":2,"Attribute2":"Test2","Attribute3":"Test","Attribute4":,"Attribute5":}]
```

On the other hand, are there any best practices in such a scenario? maybe I should convert all values to varchar?

Thank you very much for your help and any suggestions

Regards

Comment: Your 2nd JSON is not a valid JSON format. Converting all values to varchar is not best practice either! You need to have models for your JSON and Database data and use a DTO to convert from your database model to your json model. Use classes.

Comment: yeap, you are right.. this JSON is not valid. So, please tell me what is the best way to represent decimal null values from database in JSON file? Regards

Comment: null is the best way to represent a null value of any type. In your class, you need to define your nullable decimal as decimal? as well.

Comment: @anders1990 this would be a valid JSON `[{"Attribute1":10,"Attribute2":"Test","Attribute3":"Test2","Attribute4":null,"Attribute5":null},{"Attribute1":10,"Attribute2":"Test","Attribute3":"Test2","Attribute4":1.20,"Attribute5":null}]` So you would make a class with "decimal?" as proposed by bre_dev, which means nullable decimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way you can have the empty value is if you convert to string before serializing to json. Keep in mind that an empty value IS a string.

You can't get empty value from a decimal since it is not a number.

You can call ToString() right after your GetDecimal . You might want to format the string representation of decimal using:

```
.ToString("#.##")
```

To get a string representation of the number with 2 decimal points

Comment: I see, so as I understand there is no option to achieve empty value without quotes? the only option is empty string "" or any other marker like "null" after converting value to string ?

Thank you!

Comment: That's right. If you are happy with the answer, can you please flag this as answered?